# cannot change css property of desired amount of elements using eventListener due to elements being created by javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, reference, event-handling

I am attempting to change the backgroundColor of "gridElement" once "button" is clicked.

What was attempted, changing the way the elements are created to later include the event:

- cloneNode() // doesn't work with eventListeners unless you use eventDelegation, in this case there is no parentElement to delegate the event too.
- jQuery.clone() // the event is not tied directly to "gridElement" rather it is tied to "button" so jQuery.clone() would not be deep copying any associated events.

Also, attempting to make references to all gridElements:

- used window.globalVarRef = localVar. // only references the first element and not all.

How can I modify the code so that the eventListener will change all "gridElement" and not just the first?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/main.css">
        <title> Method 1 // appendChild() </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container">
            <div id="gridContainer"></div>
        </div> 
        <script>

        const gridContainer = document.getElementById('gridContainer');
       
        function createPixels(){
            let pixels = 256;
            for(let k=0;k<pixels;k++) {
                const gridElement = document.createElement('div');
                gridElement.classList.add('gridElement');
                gridContainer.appendChild(gridElement);
                window.allGridElements = gridElement;
            }
        }       

        createPixels();
        
         
        const button = document.createElement('button');
        button.classList.add('button');
        button.textContent = 'button';
        gridContainer.appendChild(button);

        function changeBkg(){
            window.allGridElements.style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
        }

        button.addEventListener('click', changeBkg);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies in your changeBkg function. To select all of the elements with the class of "gridElement", you want to use a for loop to find those elements and then change their styles. I added some basic css to the grid element so we can see the color change in action. Does that solve your issue?

```css
.gridElement {
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
background: red;
display: inline-block;
margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/main.css">
        <title> Method 1 // appendChild() </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container">
            <div id="gridContainer"></div>
        </div> 
        <script>

        const gridContainer = document.getElementById('gridContainer');
       
        function createPixels(){
            let pixels = 256;
            for(let k=0;k<pixels;k++) {
                const gridElement = document.createElement('div');
                gridElement.classList.add('gridElement');
                gridContainer.appendChild(gridElement);
                window.allGridElements = gridElement;
            }
        }       

        createPixels();
        
        const button = document.createElement('button');
        button.classList.add('button');
        button.textContent = 'button';
        gridContainer.appendChild(button);

        function changeBkg(){
         var items = document.getElementsByClassName('gridElement');
          for (let i=0; i < items.length; i++) {
            items[i].style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
          }
        }

        button.addEventListener('click', changeBkg);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```